# Your build is currently configured to use Java 19.0.2 and Gradle 7.5

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error when building my project:

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 19.0.2 and Gradle 7.5.

Possible solution:
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project
```

My `gradle-wrapper.properties` file looks like this:

```
#Mon Feb 27 20:08:12 IST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

So, the Gradle value is already 7.5. What other change do I need to make here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The Gradle version has to be changed to 7.6 for it to be compatible with Java 19.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

For Java 19, need to set gradle version as 7.6 and above.
Also check below compatibility matrix

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: this is weird. i actually looked at the table in that page. but whenever i choose v19 of oracle's open jdk it shows up as version 21 in the dropdown after selection

Answer (score 1):

In My case I upgraded gradle to 8.1,and its working now